# combine two foreach loops

Tags: php, foreach

I have two foreach loops:
1st one:

```
        foreach ($items as $key => $item) 
        {   
        $keywords = explode(' ', $qsvarus);
        $title[$key] = preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|', $keywords).')\b(?![^<]*[>])/i', '<b>$0</b>', $title[$key]);
        $infoo[$key] = preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|', $keywords).')\b(?![^<]*[>])/i', '<b>$0</b>', $infoo[$key]);
        echo '<tr><td>'.$title[$key].$infoo[$key].$item.'</tr></td>';
}
```

2nd one:

```
foreach ($linkai as $key => $linkas) {
    $i++;
    $a1 = $linkas[1];
$a2 = str_replace("download/", "files/", $a1);
$a3 = str_replace("&","&amp;", $a2);
$a4 = str_replace("amp;nbsp;","nbsp;", $a3);
echo "<div class=\"bgframe".str_replace("/i/", "/IMG/", $a4)."</div></div>";
}
```

The question is how to make those two loops to display results like this:

```
Result1 from Loop1
Result1 from Loop2
Result2 from Loop1
Result2 from Loop2
Result3 from Loop1
Result3 from Loop2
And so on...
```

Instead of:

```
Result1 from Loop1
Result2 from Loop1
Result3 from Loop1
...
Result1 from Loop2
Result2 from Loop2
Result3 from Loop2
```

Thanks

Comment: Do both arrays have the same size, or can the differ?

Comment: Have you tried nesting them with "Result" loop on the outside and the "loop" loop on the inside? The entire inner loop has to increment fully before the outer loop has to increment.

Comment: what is the value of `$key` in `$items`? is it `0,1,2...n` or associative array key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`MultipleIterator`](http://www.php.net/multipleiterator) for this:

```
$m = new MultipleIterator();
$m->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($items), 'item');
$m->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($linkai), 'linkas');

foreach ($m as $unit) {
    // $unit['item'] contains an entry from $items
    // $unit['linkas'] contains an entry from $linkai

    // your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution:

```
$output1 = array();
$output2 = array();

foreach ($items as $key => $item) 
{   
    $keywords = explode(' ', $qsvarus);
    $title[$key] = preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|', $keywords).')\b(?![^<]*[>])/i', '<b>$0</b>', $title[$key]);
    $infoo[$key] = preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|', $keywords).')\b(?![^<]*[>])/i', '<b>$0</b>', $infoo[$key]);
    $output1[] = '<tr><td>'.$title[$key].$infoo[$key].$item.'</tr></td>';
}

foreach ($linkai as $key => $linkas) {
    $i++;
    $a1 = $linkas[1];
    $a2 = str_replace("download/", "files/", $a1);
    $a3 = str_replace("&","&amp;", $a2);
    $a4 = str_replace("amp;nbsp;","nbsp;", $a3);
    $output2[] = "<div class=\"bgframe".str_replace("/i/", "/IMG/", $a4)."</div></div>";
}

$output = array_map( null, $output1, $output2 );
foreach ( $output as $lines ) {
    $lines = array_filter( $lines );
    foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
        echo $line;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is probably from Jack, but I thought my solution was interesting.
I also tried to improve your code:

```
do {
    if ($item = current($items)) {
        $key = key($items);
        $keywords = str_replace(' ', '|');
        list($infoo_str, $title_str) = preg_replace(
            "/\b({$keywords})\b(?![^<]*[>])/i",
            '<b>$0</b>',
            array($infoo[$key], $title[$key])
        );

        echo "<tr><td>{$infoo_str}{$title_str}{$item}</tr></td>";

        next($items);
    }

    if ($linkas = current($linkai)) {
        $characters = array('download/', '&', 'amp;nbsp;', '/i/');
        $replacements = array('files/', '&amp;', '&nbsp;', '/IMG/');
        $linkas = str_replace($characters, $replacements, $linkas);

        echo "<div class='bgframe{$linkas}'</div></div>";

        next($linkai);
    }
} while ($item or $linkas);
```