# Combining code so that they properly connect with eachother

Tags: php, xml, xpath, foreach

I am trying to combine

```
<?php
$names = $xml->xpath("/server/game/players/player[disconnect_time = '']/name");
$connect_times = $xml->xpath("/server/game/players/player[disconnect_time = '']/connect_time");
?>
```

with

```
<?php
foreach ($names as $name)
{
   echo $name . "<br />";
}
foreach ($connect_times as $connect_time)
{
   echo $connect_time . "<br />";
}
?>
```

So that they are linked eachother like:

$name1 - $connect_time1
$name2 - $connect_time2
$name3 - $connect_time3

But at the moment it's just echoing it out in order like:

$name1
$name2
$name3
$connect_time1
$connect_time2
$connect_time3

I am not very good at using foreach - so I was hoping to get some guidance here. Keeping the xpath is important because I only want to show the players whose disconnect_time is empty as it means that they're still in-game. (the xml stores recent players for a while)

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT: OH! And would it be possible to add an hour to the connect_time? It is 1hour behind of what it should show. I have this code - but once again, don't know how to combine it with the rest..

```
$connect_time = date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime("+1 hour",strtotime($name)));
$first  = new DateTime("now");
$second = new DateTime($connect_time);
$diff = $first->diff( $second );
```

EDIT 2: Adding the content of the XML to further help getting to a solution. Thanks for the help!

```
<server>
   <game>
      <players>
         <player>
            <name>Player 1</name>
            <connect_time>2014-03-15 09:05</connect_time>
            <disconnect_time/>
         </player>
         <player>
            <name>Player 2</name>
            <connect_time>2014-03-15 09:21</connect_time>
            <disconnect_time>2014-03-15 09:58</disconnect_time>
         </player>
         <player>
            <name>Player 3</name>
            <connect_time>2014-03-15 09:39</connect_time>
            <disconnect_time/>
         </player>
         <player>
            <name>Player 4</name>
            <connect_time>2014-03-15 09:50</connect_time>
            <disconnect_time>2014-03-15 10:00</disconnect_time>
         </player>
      </players>
   </game>
</server>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047696/combine-two-foreach-loops check this maybe it will help you to combine

Comment: I guess a simple solution would be a `for($i=0; $i<count($names); $i++)` loop, inside which you use `i` as an index... Or did I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, the solution is to select the `<player>`-node and access its children inside the `foreach`:

```
$players = $xml->xpath("/server/game/players/player[disconnect_time = '']");

foreach ($players as $player) {

    echo $player->name . " - " . date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($player->connect_time) + 3600) . PHP_EOL;

}
```

Comment: @user3397543 welcome! see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463549/subtract-time-in-php for calculating time differences!